# Kerberos Authentication in a Mixed (Windows and LINUX) Environment

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, mitkerberos

I need to map the Service principal name for the user in an Active Directory from Linux environment, where my KDC is located, to Windows.

Is there a way to map the AD user from Linux rather than mapping them using **setSPN** in the Windows environment?

**Solution tried:**

Configured Krb5-conf in Linux machine and installed krb5-usr as a client in Linux machine.

While issuing the command to add a principal name for the user using the admin user, I get this error:

```
testuser@linux106:~$ kadmin -p adminuser/admin@TEST.COM -q "addprinc user1/admin@TEST.COM"
Authenticating as principal adminuser/admin@TEST.COM with password.
kadmin: Client not found in Kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface
```

Please provide input to achieve it or tell me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

*Client not found in Kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface* means that the principal *adminuser/admin@TEST.COM* you are triying to authenticate with doesn't exists.

You can avoid authenticating by executing *kadmin.local* on KDC server

```
$ sudo kadmin.local
```

Then, use *listprincs*, *addprinc*, *delprinc* ... to manage your Kerberos database principals.

> Is there a way to map the AD user from Linux?

There is no way to map an AD user from linux, as the mapping AD_user <--> AD_principal has only sense on AD servers. (*)

(*) Note that there are no Kerberos_users in a Kerberos database, just Kerberos_principals. (Or Kerberos_user = Kerberos_principal if you prefer, anyway you can't map principals to users)