# Kerberos error after reinstall

Tags: centos7, kerberos

After a reinstall of Kerberos we're now having issues authenticating from Windows to this CentOS server.

Running `kadmin` returns the following error;

```
Authenticating as principal '' with password. kadmin: Client 'domain/user@domain.com' not found in Kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface
```

How do we go about adding this principal to the Kerberos database?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an answer for this in Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333503/client-not-found-in-kerberos-database-while-initializing-kadmin-interface

this might be helpful as well:
[Kerberos Authentication in a Mixed (Windows and LINUX) Environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/903562/kerberos-authentication-in-a-mixed-windows-and-linux-environment)